# How to mapping Map<String, byte[]> with hibernate and store values as BLOB?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a column definition in my entity, `A`, and it is a `Map<String, byte[]>`. I want to store the keys as VARCHAR and the values as BLOB in the database, then I mapped this as below:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "A_DATA", joinColumns = @JoinColumn("A_ID"))
@MapKeyColumnName(name = "A_DATA_KEY")
@Column(name = "A_DATA")
@Lob
private Map<String, byte[]> data = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();
```

I know this is not a right way to map such a column for saving the values as BLOB in the database and I now get `GenericJDBCException: Invalid column type: getCLOB not implemented`. So, would you please help me to do that?

Comment: Could you tell us which DB you are using? And did you create the column as a blob column?

Comment: Data-type of the column in DB and the exceptions of Hibernate about its use do not match. Can you check what is the data-type of column `A_DATA` in DB.

Comment: @Thomas I am using Oracle DBMS. I want hibernate create the tables.

Comment: Try creating the tables manually. Using hbm2ddl isn't advicable in a production environment anyways.

Comment: @Thomas OK thanks, I will do that.